# How to delete a member array inside a member function with this, for reassignment

Tags: c++

I have some simple code that merges two char[] into a new array. The problem is that when I've created the new array, I want to delete the original char array which was allocated in the constructor. If I don't call delete on this memory, then I'm going to get a memory leak once I reassign the m_str.

-Edit
Why am I getting an error when I call delete?

```
String()      { m_str = new char[1]; *m_str = 0; }

String& String::operator+= (const String& other)
{
    unsigned int tmpInt1, tmpInt2;

    tmpInt1 = myStrlen(this->m_str);
    tmpInt2 = myStrlen(other.m_str);

    // Allocate the new char array, make an extra space for the '\0'
    char* newChar = new char[tmpInt1 + tmpInt2 + 1];

    myStrcat(newChar, this->m_str, tmpInt1, 0);
    myStrcat(newChar, other.m_str, tmpInt2, tmpInt1);

    this->m_str[myStrlen(m_str)] = '\0';

    delete[] this->m_str;
    this->m_str = newChar;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Why you have to `delete` it or why memory leak is a problem?

Comment: @aleguna The question is why am I getting an error when I use delete like this. I don't want a memory leak.

Comment: @Gandalf458, have you heard of "Rule of Three"?

Comment: I'm avoiding use of the STL, myStrlen returns the number of characters in the array, not including the terminating null character. The same as strlen.

Comment: @aleguna not explicitly as that, but yes, I do know that those 3 things are auto-generated by the compiler.

Comment: @Gandalf - I misread the code. However, `this->m_str[myStrlen(m_str)] = '\0';` will write the `'\0'` to the position where the string is already terminated. Harmless, but not very useful.

Comment: @Gandalf458, in your case you need to implement them all because default copy constructor will make a shallow copy and you will get a double delete and crash as a result. PS: Why are you avoiding std library?

Comment: @aleguna Not allowed to use STL, due to the constraints of my assignment. I don't think it is using the copy constructor in this code, right? Passing it in by reference avoids that.

Comment: @BoPersson It is a bit redundant, but I was trying to avoid having people tell me the error is due to the string not being null-terminated.

Comment: Well I don't know that, I didn't post all your code here, did you? Besides saying that I don't need a copy constructor because I never make copies is outright silly, CC  must be there no matter what.

Comment: @aleguna trust me, I didn't make these constrtaints. The class needs a constructor (the one I've shown), a destructor, and the operator+= overloaded function.

Comment: Whoever imposed these constraints is an idiot. I'm 99% sure you are getting this crash because of double delete, which is due to lack of deep copy constructor.

Comment: @aleguna I agree that to use delete like that, I would need a copy constructor. I'm thinking that without the copy constructor, perhaps it automatically deallocates the array. If you post an answer that can address that issue, then please also include the insight that under normal circumstances you want a copy constructor. Also, lots game developers avoid the STL. Hope to see your answer and vote it up. I'm upset to have gotten a negative reputation for this problem. I feel the issue is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

Because memory leaked cannot be reused for something else in your program.  It's going to stay in use until you close the program and the system can reclaim it.

Mostly you want to clean it up so it is available again for reuse, as memory is not an infinite resource.

Perhaps for small amounts of memory, leaking it, is not a big issue, but say if you were allocating blocks of 256 bytes at a time, and lots of them, then leaking these may soon become an issue.

Comment: How can I avoid this memory leak? The call to delete is giving me an assertion error.